# AWS S3 costs outside free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and have this basic question. 
 The data stored in S3 bucket, will it incur PUT/GET cost in addition to the storage cost?

**Example scenario:** (Outside free tier) I am storing objects of size 1GB for 1 day, will I be charged for Storage cost of 1GB in addition to the PUT request cost of those objects.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, you incur costs for requests in addition to storage costs and it varies based on `storage class` and `region` you choose. Check this link https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/  for more detail.

Comment: @MadhukarMohanraju thanks for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described on [Amazon S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), costs are incurred for:

- Storage (per GB per month)
- Requests (GET, PUT, etc)
- Data Transfer (if the data is going *out to the Internet*)

All three costs apply.